# Reconnecting Kawasaki GPX 750 1998 to Keihin G301 carburator

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-system, carburetor, kawasaki

I have some issues reconnecting 1998 Kawasaki GPX fuel system to a Keihin G301 carburetor. Some of the tags that I put on carburetor have fallen off and I lost track of what hose goes where. There are two hoses for coolant and all other are fuel and vacuum. I need schematics or guidance how to reconnect the hoses.

Can anyone provide diagrams or guidance on how I can get my fuel system integrated back into the motorcycle properly?

I can supply more images if necessary.

[**Images of the fuel system, gas tank and carburetors**](https://www.flickr.com/photos/144298920@N02/)

Comment: Is that model a 1989 and not a 1998 and is it a GPX750R?

Comment: New MC chatroom.  Come hither.   http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46288/motorcycle-diaries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here are the various connections based upon your images.**

I have left the label spelling in the image provided the same as the image.  They match any misspellings in the three images.

**Image 1**

- "I don't know" marked inlet is a vacuum line.  Your petcock has two lines coming off of it.  The smaller one is for vacuum, the larger one is for fuel.

**Image 2**

- "I don't know" market inlet is for vacuum.
- "Main Fuel (Not sure)" is for your main fuel line from your petcock

**Image 3**

- "Reservoir Fuel Supply" is actually a vacuum connector.  The vacuum opens a diaphragm that allows fuel into the carburetors.  This is a safety component in case your float is stuck open so your cylinder doesn't fill with fuel and create a hydro-lock situation which could be catastrophic to your engine.
- "Main Fuel Suply" is correct and attaches to the carburetor fuel inlet from Image 2
- "Vacuum" is incorrect.  It is either a fuel tank vent hose or a drain.  Either way it would connect to a hose that routes to the bottom of the motorcycle behind the engine and before the swing arm.
- "Drain (I think...)" is possibly correct.  As above, it is either a fuel tank breather or an overflow.  One of the two.  It routes the same as described above, behind the engine.

**Carburetor Parts Explosion** *

[image]

**Fuel Tank Parts Explosion** *

[image]

Images from Kawasaki via https://www.motorcyclespareparts.eu